# jQuery 2 Editable Selectboxes - only one is working

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is utilizing [this jQuery Editable-Select Plugin](http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/). I have 2 select boxes (as you can see in the image below). They are both utilizing the classname `editable-select` and when I execute the JS - only one of them seems to be affected by the call. When I display the results of `editableSelect(...)` both select items are returned, but one is visibly untouched by the plugin. This select is not being populated by ajax, and is available to the DOM right away.

I've pulled the basic code out and put it into JSFiddle, and it works just fine, so I am not under the impression that there is a problem with the plugin or anything... I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

If I remove the class from working select box, the first one still does not work, so it's got to be something with the select box - but I really cant fingure out what.. The code for the `field1` select is copied and pasted right from the page. looks OK to me.

Where should I be looking for an error - I've been trying to debug this for a few hours now and everything looks legit. No errors in console/firebug. Please help :)

**JS**

```
theSubjectBox = $('.editable-select').editableSelect({
    bg_iframe: true,
    onSelect: function(list_item) {
        alert('List item text: '+ list_item.text() + ' Input value: '+ this.text.val());
    },
    case_sensitive: false,
    items_then_scroll: 10 
});
console.log(theSubjectBox);
```

I have also tried

```
theSubjectBox = $('#field1').editableSelect({...});
```

**Console Output**

> ```
> [select#field1.editable-select, select#insertQM_hidden_select.editable-select]    
> 0       select#field1.editable-select
> 1       select#insertQM_hidden_select.editable-select
> //The first item is clearly not touched by the plugin. Why!? :)
> ```

**HTML**

```
<!--Not Working-->
<select style="width:200px;" name="field1" id="field1" class="editable-select">
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value="Answer Needed">Answer Needed</option>
    <option value="Appointment Needed">Appointment Needed</option>
    <option value="BULLETIN">BULLETIN</option>
    <option value="Catalog/Literature">Catalog/Literature</option>
    <option value="Comment(s)">Comment(s)</option>
    <option value="Company Policy">Company Policy</option>
    <option value="F.Y.I.">F.Y.I.</option>
    <option value="IMPORTANT">IMPORTANT</option>
    <option value="Information Please">Information Please</option>
    <option value="Meeting Information">Meeting Information</option>
    <option value="Need Your Help">Need Your Help</option>
    <option value="Needs Visit">Needs Visit</option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Personnel Change">Personnel Change</option>
    <option value="Question(s)">Question(s)</option>
    <option value="Quotation Needed">Quotation Needed</option>
    <option value="Reminder">Reminder</option>
    <option value="Thank You">Thank You</option>
    <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
</select>

<!--Working Fine-->  
<select style="width:630px;" id="insertQM" name="insertQM" class="editable-select">
    <option value="">Insert Quick Message</option>
    <option value="Can I see you in my office?">Can I see you in my office?</option>
    <option value="I'll take care of it right away.">I'll take care of it right away.</option>
    <option value="I'm going to lunch now!">I'm going to lunch now!</option>
    <option value="MUST CALL IMMEDIATELY!">MUST CALL IMMEDIATELY!</option>
    <option value="No problémo">No problémo</option>
    <option value="Not yet">Not yet</option>
    <option value="Remind me later about that.">Remind me later about that.</option>
</select>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Smamati: Yes, I did. It is, in fact, the OTHER select that is not working.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jcttP/

Comment: Yes.. it works for me in JSFiddle too. But the problem is that the same code is not working on my site. :)

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else on your site...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of - problem is, how does one trace this down? I'm not getting any other errors. Is it erroneous JS - invalid HTML... grr. :)

Comment: I would suggest stripping out other JavaScript that you have and leaving just the editable select boxes and see if it works then. If it does then slowly add back the other scripts until it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **a** solution, although I'm not sure why this was happening in the first place. I just commented out the following if statement in the provided JS file. I have no idea how this item's `.data('editable-selecter')` object would have been set, but commenting this out works.

```
  //if($(this).data('editable-selecter') !== null) {
    instances[i] = new EditableSelect(this, settings);
    $(this).data('editable-selecter', i);
  //}
```